# what's error with my sql command?

Tags: mysql

the matched product name is: `$products_name`

$query ="select p.products_id, pd.products_name, p.products_price
             from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p, " .
                                     TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd
             where p.products_status = 1
             and p.products_id = pd.products_id
             and pd.language_id = '" . (int)$_SESSION['languages_id'] . "'
             and p.products_id <> :p.products_id 
             AND MATCH('products_name') AGAINST (:products_name IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)";

1, why using `" p, "`  not `" p "`

my IDE shows an alert of the command. i don't know how to correct it.

when run the query ,the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':p.products_id AND MATCH('products_name') AGAINST (:products_name IN NATURAL LAN' at line 6

ps:

```
1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':p.products_id AND MATCH(`products_name`) AGAINST (:products_name IN NATURA' at line 5
in:
[ SELECT p.products_id, pd.products_name, p.products_price FROM TABLE_PRODUCTS p INNER JOIN TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION pd ON (p.products_id = pd.products_id) WHERE p.products_status = 1 AND p.products_id <> :p.products_id AND MATCH(`products_name`) AGAINST (:products_name IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)]
```

I Want to show the relative item under the product. which match according to some parts of the `product name`

Comment: What error do you get? Can you print `$query` so we can see what's inside?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':p.products_id AND MATCH('products_name') AGAINST (:products_name IN NATURAL LAN' at line 6

Comment: How do you execute this query? Is `:p.products_id` getting replaced with a value?

Comment: Konerak, I Want to show the relative item under the product. which match according to some parts of the product name

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT p.products_id, pd.products_name, p.products_price
 FROM TABLE_PRODUCTS p
 INNER JOIN TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION pd ON (p.products_id = pd.products_id)
 WHERE p.products_status = 1
   AND pd.language_id = :lang_id   
   AND p.products_id <> :p.products_id 
   AND MATCH(products_name) AGAINST (:products_name IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
   --        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ A         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ B
   --  A = column, don't quote  B = value, can be quoted.
```

You have a syntax error in the `match` part.
column names should not be quoted in single quotes `'`, but in backticks `` ` ``.
However that's only needed for reserved words and such.

**Other problems**
You are using implicit join syntax.  That's a bad idea better to use explicit joins.

If you are using PDO, do not inject $vars in, but just use PDO for everything, it is cleaner, will execute faster and you cannot make SQL-injection mistakes.

As per your question:

> 1, why using " p, " not " p "

The `,` syntax is an implicit cross join of two tables, which you transmogrify into an inner join in your where clause: `... AND p.products_id = pd.products_id ...`.
This is SQL '89 syntax, long since improved upon by the much cleaner SQL '92 syntax.
Better to use an explicit inner join instead.

Answer (score 0):

The final query you are sending the database is:

```
select p.products_id, pd.products_name, p.products_price from table1 p, table2 pd
where p.products_status = 1
and p.products_id = pd.products_id
and pd.language_id = 'lang'
and p.products_id <> :product_id AND MATCH('products_name') AGAINST (:products_name IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

And it is wrong.

The most approximate query to work on mysql is:

```
select p.products_id, pd.product_name, p.products_price from table1 p, table2 pd 
where p.products_status = 1 and p.products_id = pd.products_id 
and pd.language_id = 'lang' and p.products_id <> pd.products_id 
AND MATCH(products_name) AGAINST ('product_name' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

But I'm not sure if it is what you want...

The "," is mandatory to separate the two tables in the from clause.

Comment: is your code, i have not changed anything... It is just how te DB receives your query (obviously the tablenames are invented by me). It is impossible my code could work... What do you want to obtain with the query exactly?

Comment: you cannot put single quotes in the match - it's expecting columns

Comment: @Johan What does not work? I have not provided any code as solution, I have just printed the query sent to the database to clarify that the "," is mandatory and thus is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

MATCH() is expecting columns. you cannot put quotes inside since they are treated as strings.

use ` instead, or nothing

```
MATCH(products_name)
MATCH(`products_name`)
```